# Applying position dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am creating a div in javascript. I use:

```
const divStyle = {left: offsetPercent + '%', 'position': 'absolute'};
<div style={divStyle}/>
```

Typescript complains that the 'absolute' value (a string) is not assignment to PositionProperty. So, how do I actually set the position?

Comment: What library are you using in the second line of your code snippet? React?

Comment: @BenjaminDavies That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is happy with:

```
const divStyle = {left: offsetPercent + '%', position: 'absolute' as 'absolute'};
```